# Spring MVC @Controller and profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-profiles

I have a spring mvc controller and I want to enable it only in some profiles (for example `development` and `test`).

I know I can use the `profile` attribute of the `beans` element in xml configuration to limit the scope of my beans, but I'm using convenient annotations for the controllers now.

Can I bind the annotated controller to given profile somehow?

Or do I have to use the "old way" (of implementing and declaring controller) without annotations and use the `beans` element in xml configuration?

Will the annotated controllers mix well with the "old ones"?

**EDIT:** another way, which comes to my mind, is to check the profile in runtime from autowired Environment instance, but this denies the inversion of control

Comment: Put a different `<component-scan>` inside a profile `<beans profile="dev">`.

Comment: Theres an @Profile annotation ?

Comment: @MikePatel Is that a question or are you telling him there is such an annotation?

Comment: There is such an annotation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is this what you mean ?

```
@Controller
@Profile("test")
public class CacheController {
}
```

[javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

Comment: Here's [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html).

Comment: I should RTFM more carefully next time, I thought that the Profile annotation is only useful in java based configuration and not with the beans.

Comment: Using the right import is also important, because `org.opengis.annotation.Profile` for example is also a type annotation.